# Qt and UI Skinning

Tags: qt

I wanted to consult with the sages here regarding Qt and skinning, get your opinion and chart a path for my development. My requirements are as follows:

1. My Qt/C++ application (cross platform with Mac, Windows and Linux versions) needs to have modular skins.
2. A skin is defined as a set of one or more elements: - Window background texture - Look/feel of UI controls such as edit boxes, drop down, radio buttons, buttons etc. - Look/feel of window "caption", resize grips etc.
3. Skins will be installed with the application installer, allowing the user to choose which one he/she wants to use. Users should be able to change skins on the fly.

Can I go the QML route? should this be custom and based on simple resources which are built into the application? Any design advice will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then stylesheet is the best way forward. You can create stylesheets similar to CSS and then pass them as command line option to your application or load on invocation to style your application at runtime. That way you can create multiple stylesheets each having a different look and feel and allow user to load them at will. Since its CSS it doesn't need any new learning and you can keep all your styling outside your source code.

Here are a list of resources that can get you up and running quickly:

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2007/11/27/theming-qt-for-fun-and-profit/

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html

Comment: Is there any way for a stylesheet to be "compiled" with the application and no be present on a file inside the installation folder? I mean, i'd like the default stylesheet to be tamper-proof, while the user should have the ability to create use his own.

Comment: It's definitely possible to compile in one or more stylesheets with the application.  Have a look at Qt's resource system, which should do it.

Comment: And I really have no idea WHY the default style should be tamper-proof? In fact, the default style is very good example how styling of your application can be done, as you can skip your entire skinning documentation. I even provide my UI files for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with QML yet, but you could also create a custom `QStyle` implementation that supports your resource format. Note that you'd lose style sheet support if you went this route.

Changing window captions is a little trickier if you want portability.

Comment: Can QStyle dictate for instance a new background image for a window (widget)? or a new resize grip look for a window?

Comment: Probably to the first, but you could also use a custom paint handler in your QMainWindow implementation. Definitely yes to the second.

Answer (score 0):

`QML`, if I understand correctly, doesn't really skin the widgets, it mainly deals with GUI layout etc etc.

`QStyle` is used to change the looks. It is a bit low-level though, and requires programming, so if you want to load different user-created skins (from an XML or so) it might be tricky to support extensive skinning. Chaining colors and a few items are easy enough though. (There might be someone else who've done something you could re-use.. not sure.)

For modifying widgets, use `QStyle::polish()`. You could use that to change the background picture (if it's a top-level window, or of a certain class). There are numerous repaint method to change almost every part of every widget.

Store/load the style using `QSettings`, by reading and setting the desired Style just after QApplication but before your main window is constructed.